# When should I use streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I just came across a question when using a `List` and its `stream()` method. While I know *how* to use them, I'm not quite sure about *when* to use them.

For example, I have a list, containing various paths to different locations. Now, I'd like to check whether a single, given path contains any of the paths specified in the list. I'd like to return a `boolean` based on whether or not the condition was met.

This of course, is not a hard task per se. But I wonder whether I should use streams, or a for(-each) loop.

**The List**

```java
private static final List<String> EXCLUDE_PATHS = Arrays.asList(
    "my/path/one",
    "my/path/two"
);
```

**Example using Stream:**

```java
private boolean isExcluded(String path) {
    return EXCLUDE_PATHS.stream()
                        .map(String::toLowerCase)
                        .filter(path::contains)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .size() > 0;
}
```

**Example using for-each loop:**

```java
private boolean isExcluded(String path){
    for (String excludePath : EXCLUDE_PATHS) {
        if (path.contains(excludePath.toLowerCase())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that the `path` parameter is always *lowercase*.

My first guess is that the for-each approach is faster, because the loop would return immediately, if the condition is met. Whereas the stream would still loop over all list entries in order to complete filtering.

Is my assumption correct? If so, *why* (or rather *when*) would I use `stream()` then?

Comment: Streams are more expressive and readable than traditional for-loops. In the later you need to be careful about intrinsics of if-then and conditions, etc. The stream expression is very clear: convert filenames to lower cases, then filter by something and then count, collect, etc. the result: a very iterative expression of the flow of computations.

Comment: There is no need for `new String[]{…}` here. Just use `Arrays.asList("my/path/one", "my/path/two")`

Comment: You are right, but I intended to show the data structure I've to work with, which is a `String[]`.

Comment: If your source is a `String[]`, there is no need to call `Arrays.asList`. You can just stream over the array using `Arrays.stream(array)`. By the way, I have difficulties understanding the purpose of the `isExcluded` test altogether. Is it really interesting whether an element of `EXCLUDE_PATHS` is literally contained somewhere within path? I.e. `isExcluded("my/path/one/foo/bar/baz")` will return `true`, as well as `isExcluded("foo/bar/baz/my/path/one/")`…

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware of the `Arrays.stream` method, thanks for pointing that out. Indeed, the example I posted seems quite useless for anyone else besides me. I'm aware of the behaviour of the `isExcluded` method, but it's really just something I need for myself, thus, to answer your question: _yes_, it is interesting for reasons I would like not to mention, as it would not fit into the scope of the original question.

Comment: Why is the `toLowerCase` applied to the constant that is already lower-case? Shouldn't it be applied to the `path` argument?

Comment: It is applied to every element of the `EXCLUDE_PATHS` list in order to ensure the elements are always _lowercase_, no matter what elements the constant might have at a later point (i.e. real paths like `C:\Program Files`). For my use case the `path` parameter is expected to be lowercase at any given time (see my **Note**), so there is no need to explicitly call `toLowerCase()` on it. Also, see @Holger's answer for additional information of the correct place of the `toLowerCase`method.

Comment: On our team, we find that the stream usage causes more issues and more bugs than for loops etc. This is becase not all of the team are stream experts, and stream code is more cryptic - you cant guess what is happening if you are not a stream expert, but anyone can read a for loop and if statements.  So in our team, we favor longer explicit code than single lines of code which have a lot of functionality but no one really knows if/how it works and if there are performance issues.  Other teams may prefer shortness of code.

Comment: Use it when you write junit to satisfy line coverage , because with streams you can skip branching in code.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès More readable? Yes, all enterprise systems today is evident of that. Not. Worst to ever be introduced to Java language. Misused and overused. Better to avoid completely. Java is not a  functional language. Generics sucks.

Comment: @JohnLittle You are right. I've never iterated a list to find anything, yet streams users and systems seem filled with that nonsense. Impossible to refactor, and so redundancy and over iteration is everywhere. In a method you might see it 5 times. Same list, finding different shit. It is also not really shorter. Rarely is.

Comment: Another option here would be to use a `Set`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, _"In the later you need to be careful about intrinsics of if-then and conditions, etc." --- contrasting that with the map/filter/collect/size idiom, and it's clear there is less to worry about with the for-each.  IOW, you're glossing over the differences needed to be understood about what `.map()` does over `.filter()`, then `.collect()`, etc.  The OP's `stream()` is less clear.

Comment: @alife not to mention that the stream approach actually iterates the entire collection, stores them in a list, then checks for size. The foreach checks for the first occurrence and returns. There is certainly another way to do it with streams, but who the f*** wants to learn a whole new api to do basic things, and can my colleague do it as well? Will he?

Comment: @mjs, the advantage to functional programming has to do with stateless-programming, and not any syntactic benefit from `.stream()`.  True, streams allow us to leverage stateless-programming such that once we get a stream to work we can add something akin to a `.parallel()` to have it seamlessly distribute itself across every core on your system (complete with load-balancing).  The _problem_ is how FP is sold in Java, which is a colossal mistake. The benefit has little to do with the `->` lambda shortcuts, and everything to do with creating a pure function that can run without modifying state.

Comment: @alife Even in your example, if I want to parellize thing I could distribute the work load inside the for loop to an executor, wait for all to finish, which is possible and I guess would require some lib for that, possibly not preferable to streams. But .parallell() is rarely used anyway and does not represent the 99.999% of regular stream use. I've used it on occasion in my own code and is probably the only time I used stream so you go a point there. That is it, and I try to limit it to that. I will probably remove it eventually though.

Comment: Along with the streams API is the now overuse of the CompletableFuture and CompletedStage API's as well. Everything is inferred and weirdly named API functions apply, thenCompose, thenApply and all kinds of crap. Methods returning generics, consuming supers of BiFunction bullshit, with generics that will have einsteins head go spinning. Impossible to read, and then you have the inferrable of everything so you can not figure out types easily. var is now making its entrance and so even harder to know what a var value = method.something() returned. I have to visit that method, and god forbid ...

Comment: ... it is is some generic bullshit that is impossible to parse. Java programmers are historically the worst programmers in the world, and then you throw this shit on them. Nice working in this industry. I work with some leading tech company now, and it is the same crap along with 100 line code line limit. Some weird stuff to parse with your eyes, Optionals, Predicates, CompletableStage and what not. All could have been just regular java code.

Comment: Just visit some of the CompletionStage API methods and try to parse that shit. Thats the Java API which is supposed to be the well written. public <U> CompletionStage<U> applyToEitherAsync
        (CompletionStage<? extends T> other,
         Function<? super T, U> fn,
         Executor executor); 

Please tell me what that means.

Comment: @mjs, the problem is buried in what you just said: `if I want to parellize thing I could distribute the work load inside the for loop to an executor, wait for all to finish`.  Streams (in concert with stateless programming) allows entirely the natural load balancing across cores.  Because of the stateless nature of it, it no longer matters which core is occupied with what.  You would have to maintain all of that by hand in that executor loop of yours.  Note: I am _not_ a fan of engineers citing FP as a win because of `()->` shortcuts.  But `.parallel()` is hard to emulate in non-fragile ways.

Comment: I am just saying that the whatever logic is to be handled is an implementation, done once. The consequence is that no one is using parellize() and using streams for everything else. Rather than .parellell() you could just call mehtod to iterate parellizized passing the lambda. So it is not streams that enable this, or the map, collect, filter ... parellilze is a method of its own really, or could be. What I mean is you do not need streams() for that, as by its own it could be a fairly simple implementation to parellize any action, as well as wait of it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Your stream implementation is slower than the for-loop.

This stream usage should be as fast as the for-loop though:

```
EXCLUDE_PATHS.stream()  
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .anyMatch(path::contains);
```

This iterates through the items, applying `String::toLowerCase` and the filter to the items one-by-one and **terminating at the first item** that matches.

Both `collect()` & `anyMatch()` are terminal operations. `anyMatch()` exits at the first found item, though, while `collect()` requires all items to be processed.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about `findFirst()` in combination with `filter()`. Apparently, I do _not_ know how to use streams as well as I thought.

Comment: There are some really interesting blog articles & presentations on the web about stream API performance, which I found very helpful for understanding how this stuff works under the hood. I can definitely recommend just researching a bit, if you're interested in that.

Comment: After your edit, I feel like your answer is the one that should be accepted, as you also answered my question in the comments of the other answer. Though, I'd like to give @rvit34 some credit for posting the code :-)

Comment: As you noted, most people would not know of all the intricate ways, such as findFirst, anyMatch or similar, and people have bigger tendency to stream the wrong way. I mean this is the prime example. It requires more knowledge to know everything about Streams and while you do your other 9 colleagues do not.

Answer (score 38):

The decision whether to use Streams or not should not be driven by performance consideration, but rather by readability. When it really comes to performance, there are other considerations.

With your `.filter(path::contains).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() > 0` approach, you are processing all elements and collecting them into a temporary `List`, before comparing the size, still, this hardly ever matters for a Stream consisting of two elements.

Using `.map(String::toLowerCase).anyMatch(path::contains)` can save CPU cycles and memory, if you have a substantially larger number of elements. Still, this converts each `String` to its lowercase representation, until a match is found. Obviously, there is a point in using

```
private static final List<String> EXCLUDE_PATHS =
    Stream.of("my/path/one", "my/path/two").map(String::toLowerCase)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

private boolean isExcluded(String path) {
    return EXCLUDE_PATHS.stream().anyMatch(path::contains);
}
```

instead. So you don’t have to repeat the conversion to lowcase in every invocation of `isExcluded`. If the number of elements in `EXCLUDE_PATHS` or the lengths of the strings becomes really large, you may consider using

```
private static final List<Predicate<String>> EXCLUDE_PATHS =
    Stream.of("my/path/one", "my/path/two").map(String::toLowerCase)
          .map(s -> Pattern.compile(s, Pattern.LITERAL).asPredicate())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

private boolean isExcluded(String path){
    return EXCLUDE_PATHS.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.test(path));
}
```

Compiling a string as regex pattern with the `LITERAL` flag, makes it behave just like ordinary string operations, but allows the engine to spent some time in preparation, e.g. using the Boyer Moore algorithm, to be more efficient when it comes to the actual comparison.

Of course, this only pays off if there are enough subsequent tests to compensate the time spent in preparation. Determining whether this will be the case, is one of the actual performance considerations, besides the first question whether this operation will ever be performance critical at all. Not the question whether to use Streams or `for` loops.

By the way, the code examples above keep the logic of your original code, which looks questionable to me. Your `isExcluded` method returns `true`, if the specified path contains any of the elements in list, so it returns `true` for `/some/prefix/to/my/path/one`, as well as `my/path/one/and/some/suffix` or even `/some/prefix/to/my/path/one/and/some/suffix`.

Even `dummy/path/onerous` is considered fulfilling the criteria as it `contains` the string `my/path/one`…

Comment: Nice insights on possible performance optimization, thanks. _Regarding the last part of your answer:_ if my reply to your comment was not satisfying, consider my example code as a mere helper for others to understand what I'm asking - rather than it being actual code. Also, you could always edit the question, if you have a better example in mind.

Comment: I take your comment that this operation is what you really want, so there is no need to change it. I’ll just keep the last section for future readers, so they are aware that this is not a typical operation, but also, that it has been discussed already and doesn’t need further comments…

Comment: Actually streams are perfect to use for memory optimization when the amount of working memory is breaking the server limit

Answer (score 22):

Yeah. You are right. Your stream approach will have some overhead. But you may use such a construction:

```
private boolean isExcluded(String path) {
    return  EXCLUDE_PATHS.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).anyMatch(path::contains);
}
```

The main  reason to use streams is that they make your code simpler and easy to read.

Comment: Is `anyMatch` a shortcut for `filter(...).findFirst().isPresent()`?

Comment: Yes it is! That's even better than my first suggestion.

Answer (score 13):

The goal of streams in Java is to simplify the complexity of writing parallel code. It's inspired by functional programming. The serial stream is just to make the code cleaner.

If we want performance we should use parallelStream, which was designed to. The serial one, in general, is slower.

There is a good article to read about  [`ForLoop`, `Stream` and `ParallelStream` Performance](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html).

In your code we can use termination methods to stop the search on the first match. (anyMatch...)

Comment: Do note that for small streams and in some other cases, a parallel stream can be slower due to startup cost. And if you have an ordered terminal operation, rather than an unordered parallelizable one, resynchronization at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Radical answer:

**Never**. Ever. **Ever.**

I almost never iterated a list for anything, especially to find something, yet stream users and systems seem filled with that way of coding.

I find it difficult to refactor and organize such code and I see redundancy and over iteration everywhere in stream heavy systems. In the same method you might see it 5 times. Same list, finding different things.

It is also not really shorter either. Rarely is. Definitely not more readable but that is a subjective opinion. Some people will say it is. I don't. People might like it due to autocompletion but in my editor Intellij, I can just `iter` or `itar` and have the for loop auto created for me with types and everything.

Often misused and overused, and I think it is better to avoid it completely. Java is not a true functional language and Java generics suck and are not expressive enough, and certainly more difficult to read, parse and refactor. Just try to visit any of the native Java stream libraries. Do you find that easy to parse?

Also, stream code is not easily extractable or refactorable unless you want to start adding weird methods that return `Optionals`, `Predicates`, `Consumers` and what not and you end up having methods returning and taking all kinds of weird generic constraints with orders and meanings only God knows what.

Too much is inferred where you need to visit methods to figure out the types of various things.

Trying to make Java behave like a functional language like **Haskell** or **Lisp** is a fools errand. A heavy streams based Java system is always going to be more complex than a none one and way less performant and more complex to refactor and maintain.

Thus also more buggy and filled with patch work. Glue work everywhere due to the redundancy often filled in such systems. Some people just don't have an issue with redundancy. I am not one of them. Nor should you be either.

When OpenJDK got involved they started adding things to the language without really thinking it thoroughly enough. It is now not just Java Streams which is an issue. Now systems are inherently more complex because they require more base knowledge of these API's. You might have it, but your colleagues don't. They sure as hell know what a for loop is and what an if block is.

Furthermore, since you also can not assign anything to a non final variable you can rarely do two things at the same while looping, so you end up iterating twice, or thrice.

Most that like and prefer the stream approach over a for loop are most likely people that started learning Java post Java 8. Those before hate it. The thing is that it is far more complex to use, refactor and more difficult to use the right way. It requires skills to not fuck up, and then even more skills and energy to repair fuck ups.

And when I say it performs worse, it is not in comparison to a for loop, which is also a very real thing but more due to the tendency such code have to over iterate a wide range of things. It is deemed so easy to iterate a list to find an item that it tends being done over and over again.

I've not seen a single system that has benefitted from it. All of the systems I have seen are horribly implemented, mostly because of it, and I've worked in some of the biggest companies in the world.

Code is definitely not more readable than a for loop and a for loop is definitely more flexible and refactorable. The reason we see so many complex shitty systems and bugs everywhere today is, I promise you due to the heavy reliance on streams to filter, not to mention the accompanied overuse of Lombok and Jackson. Those three are the hallmark of a badly implemented system. Keyword **overuse**. A patch work approach.

Again, I consider it really bad to iterate a list to find anything. Yet with Stream based systems, this is what people do all the time. It is also not rare and difficult to parse and detect that an iteration might be O(N2) while with a for loop you would immediately see it.

What is often customary to ask the database to filter things for you it is now not rare that instead a base query instead return a big list of things with all kind of iterative logic and methods to filter out the undesirables and of course they use streams to do this. All kinds of methods arises around that big list with various things to filter out things.

Often redundant filtering and thus logic too. **Over and over again.**

Of course, I do not mean you. But your colleagues. Right?

Personally, I rarely ever iterate anything. I use the right datasets and rely on the database to filter it for me. **Once**. However in a streams heavy system you will see iteration everywhere.

In the deepest method, in the caller, caller of caller, caller of the caller of the caller. Streams everywhere. It is ugly. And good luck refactoring that code that lives in tiny lambdas. And good luck reusing them. Nobody will look to reuse your nice Predicates.

And if they want to use them, guess what? They need to use more Streams. You just got yourself addicted and cornered yourself further. Now, are you proposing I start splitting all of my code in tiny Predicates, Consumers, Function and BiFcuntions? Just so I can reuse that logic for Streams?

Of course I hate it just as much in Javascript as well where over iteration is everywhere by noob frontend developers.

You might say the cost is nothing to iterate a list but the system complexity grows, redundancy increases and therefore maintenance costs and number of bugs increases. It becomes a patch and glue based approach to various things. Just add another filter and remove this, rather than code things the right way.

Furthermore, where you need three servers to host all of your users, I can manage with just one. So required scalability of such a system is going to be required way earlier than a non streams heavy system. For small projects that is a very important metric. Where you can have say 5000 concurrent users, my system can handle twice or thrice that.

I have no need for it in my code, and when I am in charge of new projects, the first rule is that streams are totally forbidden to use.

That is not to say there are not use cases for it or that it might be useful at times but the **risks associated** with allowing it far **outweighs** the benefits.

When you start using Streams you are essentially adopting a whole **new programming paradigm**. The **entire programming style of the system** will change and that is what I am **concerned about**.

You do not want that style. It is not superior to the old style. Especially on Java.

Take the **Futures API** as an example.

Sure, you could start coding everything to return a Promise or a Future, but do you really want to? Is that going to resolve anything? Can your entire system really follow up on being that, everywhere?

Will it be better for you, or are you just experimenting and hoping you will benefit at some point?

There are people that overdo **JavaRx** and overdo promises in JavaScript as well. There are really really few cases for when you really want to have things futures based and very many many corner cases will be felt where you will find that those APIs have certain limitations and you just got made.

You can build really really complex and far far more maintainable systems without all that crap.

This is what it is about. It is not about your hobby project expanding and becoming a horrible code base.

It is about what is best approach to build large and complex **enterprise systems** and ensure they remain coherent, consistent refactorable, and easily maintainable.

Furthermore, rarely are you ever working on such systems on your own.

You are very likely working with a minimum of > 10 people all experimenting and overdoing Streams.

So while you might know how to use them properly you can rest assure the other 9 really don't. They just love experimenting and learning by doing.

I will leave you with these wonderful examples of real code, with **thousands** of more similar to them:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Try refactoring any of the above. I challenge you. Give it a try. Everything is a Stream, everywhere. This is what Stream developers do, they overdo it, and there is no easy way to grasp what the code is actually doing. What is this method returning, what is this transformation doing, what do I end up with. Everything is inferred. Much more difficult to read for sure.

If you understand this, then you must be the **einstein**, but you should know not everyone is like you, and this could be your system in a very near future.

Do note, this is not isolated to this one project but I've seen many of them very similar to these structures.

One thing is for sure, horrible coders love streams.

Comment: "One thing is for sure, horrible coders love streams.". Evidence please. I would have thought that 'horrible coders' wouldn't even understand them. Or do you think that you assertion also proves the converse? It doesn't. You can hardly be said to have made a coherent case here. We get that you don't like streams, but my experience is that in their place they tend to work first time, unlike more general coding: and 'horrible coders' not understanding them is in its way a bonus. Your examples aren't self-evidently 'horrible', and it is a good bet that you are criticizing working code here.

Comment: I am not saying all Stream coders are horrible coders. I am saying horrible coders love them. If they are as you stated more difficult to use, then what would make you think that they won't attempt to use them? Furthermore, by your same statement, you are affirming that they are more complex to use, so I think you just provided your own argument against them. Why complicate your code base instead of keeping it nimble, easy and light? Also, evidence? The code pieces I attached, does it look like a good coder wrote that? Or horrible ones? Perhaps this code reads like poetry to you?

Comment: If for you this code is not "self-evidently horrible" then I do not think we will be able to agree on anything here. But your comment was noted.

Comment: Why did you replace plain text code with images? We have a rule that code should never be posted as images, because: It cannot be copy/pasted, it cannot be found with search, people depending on screen readers can't access it and images are diabled in some places (e.g. I wouldn't be able to see your code at work because my employer blocks images from several places, including Stack Overflow). These changes should be rolled back.

Comment: What i would say is that `.stream()` definitely seems to have a rite-of-passage sense to it.  And this _does_ color the subjective "readability" of the code.  For instance, despite what another person said, there is absolutely NO way that the top OP's `stream` statement is clearer _or has less to worry about_ than the for-each he supplies.  This seems to be "look at my new toy" at work or worse "if you were senior, you'd understand it".  Both of which are detrimental thought processes that have plagued our industry from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned many good points, but I just want to mention **lazy evaluation** in stream evaluation. When we do `map()` to create a stream of lower case paths, we are not creating the whole stream immediately, instead the stream is **lazily constructed**, which is why the performance should be equivalent to the traditional for loop. It is not doing a full scanning, `map()` and `anyMatch()` are executed at the same time. Once `anyMatch()` returns true, it will be short-circuited.