# Interate over char array with another int array using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to use streams in java like LINQ in .net.
I have two arrays one is a char array and the other is int array.
Now I looping with a foreach loop to print a message using the two arrays, one hold the chars and the other is just the positions where to pick the char.

Here is the code:

```
char[] letter = {115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 119, 105, 110, 100, 103, 32 };
int[] pos = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15};

for(int s:pos){
    System.out.print(letter[s]);
}
```

I want to make this using streams.

My idea was to do something like this.

```
Arrays.asList(
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15
)
.stream()
.forEach(p -> p)
```

So in the lambda expression in the forEach use the letter char array but maybe now but it straight in like

```
letter[p]
```

Comment: if i get you try this

Arrays.stream(pos).forEach(p->System.out.println(letter[p]));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `map` and access by index

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] letter = {115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 119, 105, 110, 100, 103, 32 };
    int[] pos = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15};

    Arrays.stream(pos).map(x -> letter[x]).forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Output:

```
11511697991071111181011141021081111193210511532107105110103
```

If you don't want to create `int[]` array you can use `Stream.of()`

```
Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15)
      .map(x -> letter[x])
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```

But output would be

```
stackoverflow is king
```

The difference appears because in the first example the stream was started from an int array and chars later converted to int. if you want to display the word in the first example, then replace the stream with

```
Arrays.stream(pos)
      .mapToObj(x -> (char) letter[x])
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Is it possible to bake in the arrays directly in the stream and not declare them outside, so everything in one big chunk of code. Also the output should be letters, without the MAP it worked

Comment: Added this to answer

Comment: Is it possible to add the letter array inside the map method,

Comment: What do you mean by add inside? It is already inside method `x -> letter[x]`. You want to create char array inside map?

Comment: Exactly, i want to create a char array inside the map, and the use the x from labda expresion to interate over

Comment: like this      Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15)
      .map(x -> new char[] {115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 119, 105, 110, 100, 103, 32}[x])
      .forEach(System.out::print);

Comment: I do not see any other way to do it besides yours. But it seems to me that this use of streams does not increase the readability of the code, for which streams were invented. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486428/when-should-i-use-streams

Comment: @mogren3000 recreating the char array for every stream element is very expensive. If you want to treat a sequence of `char` values like a constant, use the old idiomatic solution that is both, readable and efficient: `IntStream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15) .mapToObj("stackoverflwindg "::charAt) .forEach(System.out::print);`. If you want to be even more efficient, avoid the boxing to `Character` objects: `IntStream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,11,16,12,0,16,4,12,13,15) .map("stackoverflwindg "::charAt) .forEach(c -> System.out.print((char)c));`