# Reverse a Map (A - B List) to (B - A List)

Tags: java, java-stream

I made up this function, it seems to make the work, but I wondered if there was an even cleaner solution.

```java
    public static <K, V> Map<V, List<K>> reverseMap(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(value -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(value, entry.getKey())))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    }
```

Bonus question: I have a java 8 constraint for this one, but how could later versions improve it? I assume I'd no longer have to use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` since Java 9 introduced the `Map.entry(k, v)` function.

Comment: Because the question is about reviewing running code it is better asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: My first reaction to manually creating new `Entry` objects is usually shame, but I don't see a simple stream-based solution that wouldn't really necessitate it (As `#groupingBy` cannot partition the value list). I believe in this case, the simplest approach is actually _avoiding_ streams, and simply iterating the map, adding them into a new map alongside `Map#computeIfAbsent` for a value `List`. This would be a one-liner inside of 2 loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not necessitate streams in your question, I'm going to advocate for a non-stream solution:

```
//example input
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13, 4));
map.put(2, Arrays.asList(21, 22, 23, 4));
map.put(3, Arrays.asList(31, 32, 33, 4));
//reversing
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> reversed = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((key, list) -> {
    list.forEach(value -> {
        reversed.computeIfAbsent(value, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(key);
    });
});
//end result:
//{32=[3], 33=[3], 4=[1, 2, 3], 21=[2], 22=[2], 23=[2], 11=[1], 12=[1], 13=[1], 31=[3]}
```

In your stream-based solution, you will be creating new `Entry` objects per key-(list-value) pair in the map, which will then have to make additional entries when recombined into a map. By using a direct approach, you avoid this excess object creation and directly create the entries you need.

Note that [not everything has to be a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489219/1786065), the "old" way of doing things can still be correct, if not better (in readability and performance terms) than a Stream implementation.